# How to scan and connect to Bluetooth classic for iOS in Xamarin forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.ios, ios-bluetooth

I'm trying to implement Bluetooth for my project. I was able to implement **BLE** but I have to go with **Bluetooth classic** because of some hardware issue. So for Bluetooth classic implementation I have gone through [this post](https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/02/07/connect-a-barcode-reader-to-a-xamarin-forms-app-via-bluetooth/) and I used source code from [this post](https://github.com/acaliaro/TestBth). But in that they are trying to connect to **already paired device**. But my requirement is to **scan and connect to available Bluetooth** classic device not BLE device. And also there **should not be any pairing dialogue** appearing while connecting. I even tried to check if there is any **Bluetooth classic scanner application** in app store for reference but I didn't find any. There are only BLE scanner application in app store. I have no clue how to proceed forward any suggestions?

Comment: iOS apps can only connect to [MFi enabled](https://mfi.apple.com) Bluetooth classic devices.  This is why you can't find any classic BL scanner apps; it isn't possible to build such a thing.  Unless your hardware contains an MFi chip from Apple you will not be able to use classic Bluetooth profiles, such as SPP, to communicate with it.

Comment: @Paulw11 If I have MFI chip will I be able to do scan operation and do the pairing without pairing dialogue?

Comment: Pairing is always required for legacy Bluetooth. The external connectivity framework that is used by mfi makes it possible to pair in your app rather than having to go to the settings app. Apple provides more information once you are signed up as an MFi licensee.

Comment: @Paulw11 I know pairing is necessary. But I want to do it without user prompt. In BLE they won't show any pairing dialogue but in Bluetooth classic they were showing pairing request with code. So will I be able to avoid that if I am MFI certified?

Comment: In BLE pairing is optional; It is only required if you use encrypted communication, in which case a pairing dialog is triggered in the app.  With classic Bluetooth profiles you should be able to avoid a pairing dialog if you use "Just Works" pairing, but joining the MFi program isn't a trivial undertaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS apps can only connect to MFi enabled Bluetooth classic devices. This is why you can't find any classic BL scanner apps. Unless your hardware contains an MFi chip from Apple you will not be able to use classic Bluetooth profiles, such as SPP, to communicate with it.